# React, css not loading but importing correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have recently started making an app using electron-react-boilerplate, but for some reason when i import my css from any ohter files than the main App.tsx they get imported but not loaded, here is my App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Journal from './Journal';
import './App.global.css';

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Journal />
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Here is my Journal.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import j_background from './res/j_background.svg';
import './css/Journal.css';

function Journal() {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="j_background">
        <img id="background_img" src={j_background} alt="Journal background." />
      </div>
      <p>Hey</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default Journal;
```

Everything that is in ./css/Journal.css does not get applied but the app is compiled correctly?

Comment: show your directory tree.

Comment: you have to add your folder structure, then we can help you.

Comment: Hi, here is my tree https://imgur.com/a/womQoXw

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS files must be named like "FileName.module.css". So just put .module in front of your name of css file like that:

```
Journal.module.css
```

This Works fine on React version:

```
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-dom": "^16.9.0",
"react-scripts": "3.1.0"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, adding module like you explained did not work but adding global works. im not sure why.

Comment: css-modules provides :global that can be used to include locally in your code css files that will included globally in application. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726698/using-global-css-files-with-css-modules